# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class financeiro.util.JpaUtil

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xhtml, persistence

I need help to display a page of consultation results of the ebook Algaworks. Any help will be welcome!

Console (Log file)

```
 jul 25, 2016 10:42:45 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: #{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:559)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 29 more

jul 25, 2016 10:42:45 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException obtido durante o processamento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
jul 25, 2016 10:42:45 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: #{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: #{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:559)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /ConsultaLancamentos.xhtml @10,65 action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'consultaLancamentosBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 29 more
```

--->  Persistence.xml (/src/main/resources/META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="FinanceiroPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.janaina.financeiro.model.Pessoa</class>
        <class>com.janaina.financeiro.model.Lancamento</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/financeiro" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---> ConsultaLacamentos.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Consulta de lançamentos</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h1>Consulta de lançamentos</h1>
    <h:form id="frm">
        <h:dataTable value="#{consultaLancamentosBean.lancamentos}"
            var="lancamento" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Pessoa" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.pessoa.nome}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.descricao}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Tipo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.tipo}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Valor" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.valor}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Data de vencimento" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.dataVencimento}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Data de pagamento" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.dataPagamento}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---> ConsultaLacamentosBean.java

```
package com.janaina.financeiro.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.janaina.financeiro.model.Lancamento;
import com.janaina.financeiro.util.JpaUtil;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConsultaLancamentosBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Lancamento> lancamentos;

    public void consultar() {
        EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Lancamento> query = manager.createQuery("from Lancamento", Lancamento.class);
        this.lancamentos = query.getResultList();
        manager.close();
    }

    public List<Lancamento> getLancamentos() {
        return lancamentos;
    }
}
```

---> JpaUtil.java

```
package com.janaina.financeiro.util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

//JpaUtil armazena a instância compartilhada de EntityManagerFactory em uma variável estática
//Qualquer código terá acesso fácil e rápido
//Sempre que for preciso uma EntityManager basta chamar:
//EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

public class JpaUtil {
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    static {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FinanceiroPU");
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the exception trace, your class JPAUtil has not been initialized successfully. And i guess it is because the jpa facetory is not created successful here
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FinanceiroPU");

Comment: What do you think I could do?

Comment: The entity factory is not initialized properly due to some reason. and you may found out the reason from the log, console, may be the database info has typo. Or can you put the whole log file ?

Comment: Added the full log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! I realized that the causes of my problem were:

1) I was using Java JRE instead of JDK in the project. To fix this I did the following: Rigth-click on Project> Properties> Java Build Path> Libraries> selected JRE I was using> Edit> Installed JREs> Search> JDK path (C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_101).

2) Then I realized that I was not able to connect to PostgreSQL. Then I uninstalled PostgreSQL and also deleted its directory in Program Files, then I reinstalled!

3) Finally: Rigth-click on Project> Run as> Maven> Maven Clean and then Rigth-click on Project> Run as> Maven> Maven install

The steps above worked for me.. I hope they help others!

My (web.xml):

```
<context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
                <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

        <persistence-unit name="FinanceiroPU">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <class>com.janaina.financeiro.model.Lancamento</class>
                <class>com.janaina.financeiro.model.Pessoa</class>

                <properties>
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/financeiro" />
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />

                        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```